# MongoDB find all the object that contains an array which has consecutive matching value

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

I have a MongoDB collection which looks like this:

```json
{
  _id: "some-long-id-1"
  name: "John Doe",
  activities: [
    { name: "Lunch", status: "SCHEDULED" },
    { name: "Playing Football", status: "COMPLETED" },
    { name: "Workout", status: "COMPLETED" },
  ]
},
{
  _id: "some-long-id-2"
  name: "Jane Doe",
  activities: [
    { name: "Lunch", status: "COMPLETED" },
    { name: "Playing Football", status: "SCHEDULED" },
    { name: "Workout", status: "COMPLETED" },
  ]
}
```

I want to query all the objects which has `activities` which contains at least one consecutive `COMPLETED` status. For example, the query should return `some-long-id-1` object as it has a consecutive `COMPLETED` status in the activities array. It shouldn't return `some-long-id-2` as even though there are two arrays with `COMPLETED` status but they are not consecutive.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a $reduce to do this. Use a tuple of flag `consecutiveFound` to store if consecutive "COMPLETED" is found; and `lastStatus` to store the status of last element.

The initial value of the accumulator can be like this:

```
{
    "consecutiveFound": false,
    "lastStatus": ""
}
```

For the logic of `$reduce`, if `consecutiveFound` is `true`, we have found consecutive already so keeping `"consecutiveFound": true`.
If `"consecutiveFound": false`, we just keep comparing `lastStatus` and current status to see whether they are both completed. We only update the accumulator value to `"consecutiveFound": true` when we found both are `COMPLETED`. Remember to update the current value to `lastStatus` in accumulator everytime.

```
{
    "$reduce": {
        "input": "$activities",
        "initialValue": {
        "consecutiveFound": false,
        lastStatus: ""
        },
        "in": {
        "$cond": {
            "if": {
            $or: [
                {
                $eq: [
                    "$$value.consecutiveFound",
                    true
                ]
                },
                {
                $and: [
                    {
                    $eq: [
                        "$$value.lastStatus",
                        "COMPLETED"
                    ]
                    },
                    {
                    $eq: [
                        "$$this.status",
                        "COMPLETED"
                    ]
                    }
                ]
                }
            ]
            },
            "then": {
                "consecutiveFound": true,
                lastStatus: "$$this.status"
            },
            "else": {
                "consecutiveFound": false,
                lastStatus: "$$this.status"
            }
        }
        }
    }
}
```

Here is the [Mongo playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/0P8T8vEFXpF) for your reference.

Answer (score 1):

Query

- reduce array to a number (that counts the consecutive that we find)

  - 0 not found
  - 1 found one
  - 2 found 2
- we need the reduce result to be = 2
- if 2 => keep 2
  else if "completed" => inc the number
  else 0 (restart counting)

[PlayMongo](https://cmql.org/playmongo/?q=6228b275c2de7b441c4b4999)

```js
aggregate(
[{"$match": 
    {"$expr": 
      {"$eq": 
        [{"$reduce": 
            {"input": "$activities",
              "initialValue": 0,
              "in": 
              {"$switch": 
                {"branches": 
                  [{"case": {"$eq": ["$$value", 2]}, "then": "$$value"},
                    {"case": {"$eq": ["$$this.status", "COMPLETED"]},
                      "then": {"$add": ["$$value", 1]}}],
                  "default": 0}}}}, 2]}}}])
```